# Build time when referencing android library project with Netbeans

Tags: android, netbeans, ant

couldn't find an answer for this. I'm using Netbeans to develop Android applications. I'm trying to reference actionbarsherlock in my project which works just fine. My problem is, that the ant build-tool always builds the actionsbarsherlock library before building my project which is pretty time consuming. Is there a way to tell ant, only to build the library project when it's necessary (in my case never, because I won't make any changes to actionbarsherlock)?

Thanks,
Michael

Update: As Raghav Sood stated in the comment referencing the ABS as a jar file helps with the build time but if you reference it that way you can't use the resources of ABS e.g. Theme.Sherlock, etc.

Comment: If you're never going to make changes, just take the jarfile from the bin folder of ABS and include it in your project instead of including the entire library

Comment: Okay, now I feel stupid. Thought I've tried that earlier. Thanks heaps

Comment: @micheal I've added my comment as an answer. Please accept it if its solved your problem, so that your question isn't in the unanswered que anymore.